# Get Hostname in Apache Camel Spring DSL configuration file

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel

I want to load configuration properties per machine/hostname.

I have as resources several properties files and I want that Apache Camel load specific properties file depending on machine's Hostname.

**Hostname1**: sql-hostname1.properties, paths-hostname1.properties

**Hostname2**: sql-hostname2.properties, paths-hostname2.properties

I'm using Camel propertyPlaceholder

```
<propertyPlaceholder id="placeholder"
        location="classpath:sql-hostname1.properties,
                  classpath:paths-hostname1.properties" />
```

I tried to get the hostname as a environment property  `${env:hostname}`  or a system property `${hostname}` but none works.

Any ideas?

Comment: `sql-${sysenv.computername}.properties` works perfectly. I would prefer a hostname property because "COMPUTERNAME" does not exist on Linux systems

Comment: Also you can use any predefined environment variable  of you container. This variable can be different for different hosts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about configuring a spring bean, and using spring expression language to get the hostname? See for example [this blog post](http://city81.blogspot.com/2011/11/using-spring-expression-language-for.html).

Comment: Thank you! 

`<bean id="properties" class="org.apache.camel.component.properties.PropertiesComponent">
  <property name="location" value="classpath:config-#{inetAddress.hostName}.properties" />
 </bean>
 <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">`
VS
`<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
  <propertyPlaceholder id="placeholder"
   location="classpath:config-#{inetAddress.hostName}.properties" />`

Comment: First one works, second doesn't. **`#{something}`** is not supported yet inside a Camel Context in Spring DSL.